# Loading Script in Rails 7 Turbo Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, stimulusjs

I was trying to add this script into the page.

```
<script>
(
    function(d){
    var s = d.createElement("script");
    s.setAttribute("data-account", "azj4WdAV8Nq");
    s.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.userway.org/widget.js");
    (d.body || d.head).appendChild(s);
})(document)
```

This script loads once, and when I click on other pages, the scripts doesn't work. I tried wrapping this code into a Stimulus Controller too, the response is same.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
            const element = document.createElement("script")
            element.setAttribute("data-account", "azj4WAdV8Nq")
            element.setAttribute("src", "https://cdn.userway.org/widget.js")
            const r = document.body.appendChild(element)
    }
}
```

Please guide me with the correct method of wrapping this code so that it will load in every page load.

Comment: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

Comment: Tried using `document.addEventListener("turbo:load"...)` but every time the script tag is appended multiple times.

Comment: Yes, that's because your code is non-idempotent. When dealing with a persistent browser session you have to step up your JS game and check if the transformation you are going to do has already been performed. In this case you need to check if the script has already been loaded. Even with that done there is a very real chance that whatever `widget.js` is it won't actually work with Turbo as its also non-idempotent.

Comment: [The Turbolinks docs](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent) have a pretty good explaination of this and all the basic concepts can be transferred over to Turbo. Note that this isn't really just a Turbo thing or a Rails thing. It's a universal problem when you're dealing with applications that replace the page contents with AJAX. You can't just write code like its 2010 and hook everything onto the DOM ready event and expect everything to be hunky dory and a lot of legacy code just won't work.

Comment: Thanks @max, I will inform the userway.org about this issue. May be they will  update their widget.